# Proxy multi-part file from express server to golang micro service

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to proxy a file as multi-part-form data from an express-gateway to golang microservice. But I am getting error at my golang microservice, say "NextPart: EOF".

When trying to hit the micro service directly with the same request body, everything works fine. So my guess is, the issue is most probably in the gateway side.